# Renaming duplicated rows

Tags: r

I've got a time-series dataframe that looks like this:

```
...
year    site
1987    ak12
1976    ak12
1766    ak13
1818    ak13
1987    ak12
2001    ak12
...
```

As you can see some site names are duplicated (in this case ak12). I want to rename one time-series of ak12 to some unique name (e.g. 'ak12_a'), without sorting the rows. Like this:

```
...
year    site
1987    ak12
1976    ak12
1766    ak13
1818    ak13
1987    ak12_a
2001    ak12_a
...
```

I know about the `make_unique` function but I don't know how to apply it in this case, since the rows are duplicated anyway because they follow the year column. So I need some code that whenever it 'meets' the second duplicate, it will rename all of its rows. How can I do this?

Comment: Please show what the end result should look like. Right now it's not clear which `ak12` should be renamed. For example, should the rows be ordered by year before this takes place?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I amended the post! Hope it is ok!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making a nested for loop that runs every item for checking of duplicates.

```
count = 1 #for the duplicate count
for(a in 'dataframe'){
    for(b in 2:'dataframe'){
        if (equal(a,b)) { #please check on this one, not sure about the command
            b = paste(a,"_",count)
}
}
}
```

I typed this on the go without doing a test run, but hopefully it would work for you. Please point out if there's something wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(site = case_when(duplicated(site) ~ str_c(site, '_a', sep = ''), TRUE ~ site))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   year [5]
   year site  
  <dbl> <chr> 
1  1987 ak12  
2  1976 ak12  
3  1766 ak13  
4  1818 ak13  
5  1987 ak12_a
6  2001 ak12
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 6 x 2
   year site 
  <dbl> <chr>
1  1987 ak12 
2  1976 ak12 
3  1766 ak13 
4  1818 ak13 
5  1987 ak12 
6  2001 ak12
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df <- within(df, site <- ave(site, year, FUN = make.unique))
```

Output

```
> df
  year   site
1 1987   ak12
2 1976   ak12
3 1766   ak13
4 1818   ak13
5 1987 ak12.1
6 2001   ak12
```

Data I used

```
structure(list(year = c(1987L, 1976L, 1766L, 1818L, 1987L, 2001L
), site = c("ak12", "ak12", "ak13", "ak13", "ak12", "ak12")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, site := make.unique(site), year]
```